# Hamburger Responsive Button Click Event BUG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an annoying bug with a Hamburger button. I found on stackoverflow how to hide the dropdown menu when it is clicked somewhere else on the document but this lead to a bug where If I want to close the menu by **clicking again** on the hamburger icon it hides for a second and shows back again.

Advice on what I did wrong?

UPDATE: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/scuzgvmq/
Click on the button to slidedown and click agian to see the BUG

```
$('.hamburger').click(function() {
  $('#header .responsive-menu').slideToggle();
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
   var container = $("#header .responsive-menu");

  if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
     && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
  {
      container.hide('slow');
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="responsive-menu">
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
</ul>

<div class="hamburger"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the trigger isnt the hamburger button either like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yygh95qz/)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var container = $(".responsive-menu");
        var hamburger = $(".hamburger");

        hamburger.on('click', function () {
            container.slideToggle();
            container.addStyle('display:block');
        });

        $(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {

            if (!container.is(e.target) && !hamburger.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
            {
                container.hide('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```